# How can I accept self-signed server certificates from a whitelist in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to accept self-signed certificates in a NSURLConnection, as many have before me.  The catch is that I only want to accept certs from a whitelist of certs I trust.  I'd settle for figuring out how to accept a single cert.  Here's the code I've got so far in my NSURLConnectionDelegate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"trusted" ofType:@"der"];
        NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData;
        SecCertificateRef myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, myCertData);
        SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
        SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
        CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)certArray, 1, NULL);
        SecTrustRef myTrust;
        OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(myCerts, myPolicy, &myTrust);

        SecTrustResultType trustResult;
        if (status == noErr) {
            status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);
        }
        BOOL trusted = NO;

        if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified) {
            // I never get here.  Instead, trustResult is always kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure
            trusted = YES; 
        }

        if (trusted) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust]
                 forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } else {
            [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
        CFRelease(myTrust);
        CFRelease(myCerts);
        CFRelease(myPolicy);
        CFRelease(myCert);
        CFRelease(myCertData);
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

As you can see in the comment, I never actually get kSecTrustResultUnspecified, which is what I expect to get.  I verified that my cert is correct, and in the correct format (DER).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.  It turns out you just need to check the server trust, and actually use the cert data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    BOOL trusted = NO;
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"trusted" ofType:@"der"];
        NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        CFDataRef certDataRef = (__bridge_retained CFDataRef)certData;
        SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);
        SecPolicyRef policyRef = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();
        SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { cert };
        CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)certArray, 1, NULL);
        SecTrustRef serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
        SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);
        SecTrustResultType trustResult;
        SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);
        trusted = (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified);
        CFRelease(certArrayRef);
        CFRelease(policyRef);
        CFRelease(cert);
        CFRelease(certDataRef);
    }
    if (trusted) {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you get `trusted.der` file?

Comment: You can look up a tutorial online for creating one, and then package it with your app.  Google should be able to help with the rest.

Comment: I'm just curious that there might be a way, like Google Chrome, to just auto generate this inside the app itself. Thanks btw.

Comment: SecCertificateRef cert -- my cert Variable is showing nil. what could be the probable reason.

Comment: The created policyRef is useless in this example, it's not even used. The returned server trust already has got a SSL policy set.